# iPhone app versioning in free and fee version for use with OpenFeint?

Tags: iphone, versioning, openfeint

I have a question about iPhone app versioning.

I know there is the build version number (BundleVersion) and the release
version number (BundleShortVersionString) which is visible to customers.

I want to make a free version of the app and the full version.

I assume these versions should have the same release version number (e.g. 1.0),
but can they have different bundle versions?

I need different bundle versions because I am using OpenFeint for keeping highscores, and I want just one leaderboard in the free version, and all the others in the full version. 
I am really not sure how to do this..Is there maybe an option to hide the leaderboards from inside the code?

I would appreciate any help, tnx :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set any bundle version. It does not matter for OpenFeint.
You need use some AppID from OF, for two application. And you'll got one project for Open Feint. And then comment code that use another leaderboard for lite version, and you left one leader board in the free version.